# Oracle columns returned by Function

Tags: oracle

I created a function that returns matched columns between two tables. The function returns the result correctly.

How to write the result from the function as columns in select statmenet ?

Here is my Function script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GML.GML_GET_COLUMNS (P_PREFIX VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   V_COLUMNS   VARCHAR2 (1000);

   CURSOR CUR_COLUMNS
   IS
      SELECT   COLUMN_NAME
        FROM   USER_TAB_COLUMNS
       WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'GML_SCENARIOS'
               AND COLUMN_NAME IN
                        (SELECT   COLUMN_NAME
                           FROM   GML_FILE_COLUMNS
                          WHERE   UPPER (ROW_PREFIX) NOT IN
                                        ('A', 'T', 'S', 'C', 'PH', 'AD')
                                  AND UPPER (ROW_PREFIX) = P_PREFIX);
BEGIN
   FOR I IN CUR_COLUMNS
   LOOP
      V_COLUMNS := V_COLUMNS || ',' || I.COLUMN_NAME;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN V_COLUMNS;
END;
```

For example: If the function returns: `'ID,First_name,Last_name'`, how could i use the result as like as following statement:

```
select ID,first_name,Last_name from gml_scenarios
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the suggested output as you expected?

Comment: Example  : If the function return lets say this result : ID,First_name,Last_name . how could i use the result as column like this statement (select ID,first_name,Last_name from gml_scenarios ) ?

Comment: Is the desired result of the end statement - `'ID, first_name, last_name'` or rather something like - `101, Jhon, Smith`?

Comment: the desired result is the column name like id ,first_name,last_name and its dynamic not static depending on function results . if the function return (id,name,age ) the column should be id,name,age in the select statement

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have such a code :

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GML_GET_COLUMNS(P_PREFIX VARCHAR2,P_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2)
IS

   TYPE ScnCurTyp IS REF CURSOR;
   scn_cv   ScnCurTyp;
   scn_rec  gml_scenarios%ROWTYPE;
   sql_stmt VARCHAR2(32000);

   CURSOR CUR_COLUMNS
   IS
      SELECT   COLUMN_NAME
        FROM   USER_TAB_COLUMNS
       WHERE   TABLE_NAME = upper(p_table_name)
         AND   COLUMN_NAME IN
                        (SELECT   COLUMN_NAME
                           FROM   GML_FILE_COLUMNS
                          WHERE   UPPER (ROW_PREFIX) NOT IN
                                        ('A', 'T', 'S', 'C', 'PH', 'AD')
                                  AND UPPER (ROW_PREFIX) = P_PREFIX)
BEGIN
   FOR I IN CUR_COLUMNS
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( lpad(I.COLUMN_NAME,20,' ') );
   END LOOP;


   sql_stmt := 'SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM  '||v_table_name;
   OPEN scn_cv FOR sql_stmt;
   LOOP
     FETCH scn_cv INTO scn_rec;
     EXIT WHEN scn_cv%NOTFOUND;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lpad(scn_rec.id,20,' ') || '  ' || lpad(scn_rec.first_name,20,' ')|| '  ' || lpad(scn_rec.last_name,20,' '));
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE scn_cv;

END;
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> variable i_prefix varchar2;
SQL> variable i_table varchar2;
SQL> exec gml_get_columns(:i_prefix,:i_table);
```

Comment: Sir , how could i use this code in the select statemenet , i am still a fresh programer

Comment: @YF i've edited my answer, hope this will be helpful

Comment: It is static code for example if the result of function is four column, it wont work correctly.

Comment: @YF no, it works correctly but i know, u r right about being static, i couldn't find a full-dynamic one wherever i roam thru' among oracle docs, if you have a better solution, please share with us.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command for getting your goal:

```
select 'select ' || GML.GML_GET_COLUMNS('Your text') || ' from gml_scenarios ' from dual;
```

Comment: Yes, because of that the return of the function that is only String that is concated with many string is OK

Comment: You can test it

Comment: Could you execute your statement in a client of our choice and than add resulting output.

Comment: This returns a string. So how does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: Because the count of its column does not clear, I think that the first step get query and second step execute it

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you say ...

> "i am still a fresh programer "

.. which is why it is unfortunate that you have started on something which is very difficult.

SQL is a strongly typed language, because databases are machines for storing **state**. Oracle RDBMS is designed to raise an exception when it cannot predict the outcome of a SQL statement when it executes (this is the reason [why badly-designed triggers hurl mutating table exceptions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/mutating-table-exceptions)).

So there is no way you can assemble a string like `'ID,First_name,Last_name'` and use it in a SELECT statement. You need Dynamic SQL.

So you could do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GML.GML_GET_COLUMNS (P_PREFIX VARCHAR2)
   RETURN sys_refcursor
IS
   V_COLUMNS   VARCHAR2 (1000);

   CURSOR CUR_COLUMNS
   IS
      SELECT   COLUMN_NAME
        FROM   USER_TAB_COLUMNS
       WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'GML_SCENARIOS'
               AND COLUMN_NAME IN
                        (SELECT   COLUMN_NAME
                           FROM   GML_FILE_COLUMNS
                          WHERE   UPPER (ROW_PREFIX) NOT IN
                                        ('A', 'T', 'S', 'C', 'PH', 'AD')
                                  AND UPPER (ROW_PREFIX) = P_PREFIX);

   return_value sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
   FOR I IN CUR_COLUMNS
   LOOP
      V_COLUMNS := V_COLUMNS || ',' || I.COLUMN_NAME;
   END LOOP;

   open return_value for
        'select '|| V_COLUMNS || ' from gml_scenarios ';

   RETURN return_value;
END;
```

`sys_refcursor` maps to Java JDBC and ODBC `ResultSet`. They are harder to use in PL/SQL because there we need to fetch things into know target variables. This remains true even with Oracle 12c and its new [DBMS_SQL.GET_RESULT()](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#GUID-1D6A4302-CBA0-47A6-B4A7-80B089DF4E61) functionality.